# Display image uploaded using request-scoped bean

Tags: ejb, richfaces, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

I'm trying to upload a an image file to a database. Before the image is saved, I'd like to display it to the user.

I have a request-scoped bean, `UserInfoBean` (that I cannot change from being request-scoped) that I'm trying to use to save the data, however the `preview` byte[] is null when paint is called. Is there a way to be able to save `preview`,  or `image`, the UploadItem to be accessed when paint() is called?

info.xhtml code:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="preview" 
                    <a4j:mediaOutput id="imgPreview"
                                     element="img"
                                     mimeType="image/jpeg"
                                     createContent="#{userInfo.paint}"
                                     cacheable="false"
                                     style="width:150px; height:100px;" />
                    <br/>
 </a4j:outputPanel>

  <a4j:outputPanel id="signatureStampDisplay">
            <br/>                
            <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{userInfo.uploadImage}"
                             id="upload"
                             listHeight="40px"
                             acceptedTypes="#{userInfo.supportedTypes}"
                             ontyperejected="alert('Only JPG, GIF, PNG, BMP, and TIF files are accepted');"
                             maxFilesQuantity="1"
                             immediateUpload="true"
                             autoclear ="true"
                             disabled="#{userInfo.stampSet}">
                             <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete"
                                          limitToList="true"
                                          reRender="preview"/>
            </rich:fileUpload>

        </a4j:outputPanel>
```

Part of UserInfoBean, with `UploadItem` image and `byte[]` preview :

```
public void uploadImage(UploadEvent evt) throws IOException{
        image = evt.getUploadItem();
        if(image != null){
             //preview is a byte[]
             preview = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(image.getFile());
        }
    }

public void paint(OutputStream stream, Object object) throws IOException{
        if(preview != null){
             stream.write(preview);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add `stream.close();` after `stream.write(preview);` + you need set proper `mimeType` in `a4j:mediaOutput`.

Comment: @VasilLukach unfortunately the `paint` sees `preview` as null. I did make your recommended changes, though, thank you for that.

Comment: Was your upload successful? If yes, store preview in other place with longer scope or in DB and try repaint again. Maybe your data is not available because bean is request-scoped.

Comment: The upload was. I think the issue was that it is request-scoped, but due to how other things on the page interact with the larger site, I had to keep it request-scoped or else face a huge rewrite.  I think I was able to successfully use a `HttpSession session.setAttribute(name, object)` to pass the image, and am testing it now.

Comment: @VasilLukach I have posted what worked for me in case you are curious. Thank you for helping, I noticed you also helped in a question I had yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

It was unable to be passed due to the bean being request-scope.

Using an HttpSession object `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;`

I was able to store the byte[] `preview` while it was needed, removing it from the session after it has been displayed in `paint`

```
public void uploadImage(UploadEvent evt) throws IOException{
        image = evt.getUploadItem();
        if(image != null){
             preview = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(signature.getFile());
             HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
             session.setAttribute("preview", preview);
        }
    }

public void paint(OutputStream stream, Object object) throws IOException{
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        preview = (byte[]) session.getAttribute("preview");
        if(preview != null){
            stream.write(preview);
            stream.close();
            session.removeAttribute("preview");
            signaturePreview = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: To add to this, using an <a4j:keepAlive > in the html will also not work. It stores the uploaded info in the view scope, which cannot be accessed by the createContent attribute of the a4j:mediaOutput, also necessitating this workaround